# output the value of each iteration: bisection method

Tags: for-loop, iteration, bisection

I am using the bisection method to solve for the outlet concentration of a stream coming off a reactor. I am wanting my code to give me its "guess" for each iteration and list it in sheet2 alongside the iteration number and I can't seem to figure it out. Currently it is working and giving me an accurate guess but it is only for iteration 20 and I need it for each iteration 1-20. 
Thanks!

```
Option Explicit


Function Roots(F, v, k, vol, a, b)
'F is inlet molar flow rate, v is the volumetric flow rate out of the reactor, k is the reaction constant, and vol is the volume of the reactor

    Dim Clow As Double
    Dim Chigh As Double
    Dim Cmid As Double
    Dim i As Integer
'indicating what the variables are
    Clow = a
    Chigh = b
    Cmid = (a + b) / 2
'Setting the number of iterations
    For i = 1 To 20
        If solvefunction(Clow, F, v, k, vol) * solvefunction(Cmid, F, v, k,     vol) < 0 Then
        Chigh = Cmid
        Cmid = (Clow + Chigh) / 2
    Else
        Clow = Cmid
        Cmid = (Clow + Chigh) / 2
    End If
    Next i
    Roots = Cmid

End Function

Function solvefunction(C, F, v, k, vol)
'This is the function that is going to actually do the calculation

    solvefunction = F - (v * C) - (k * (C ^ 2) * vol)
End Function
```